# Identification of a spider — South India

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, arachnology

I found this spider jumping around in my garden , to describe it is blue and black . I noticed that it has strong front legs and a pointed posterior , it has blue designs on a black body . I live in South India ,ie , a tropical region . It is approximately 1cm in length .[image: The image of said spider]

Comment: was that two-three mm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to me like [*Thiania bhamoensis*](https://wiki.nus.edu.sg/display/TAX/Thiania+bhamoensis+%28Araneae%3A+Salticidae%29+Metellic+Blue+Jumper) (Metallic Blue Jumper), whose species distribution includes India. It has a notably pointy abdomen, as you noted, and the listed size range appears to be consistent as well.

I do not believe this is *Phidippus audax* due to the colour inconsistency (only the chelicerae are blue) as well as the fact that the known species distribution lies entirely within North and South America.

Comment: Yes , seems like a female since , it's greenish .The body design patterns and habitat all checks out .

Answer (score 0):

This is [Phidippus audax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phidippus_audax) commonly known as Jumping spider or Daring Jumping spider.

Comment: Idk anything about spiders but isn't the colours different .

Comment: -1. *Phidippus audax* is an American species; the OP is in India. Also, answers should be detailed and explain *why* an answer is correct. Please update accordingly or consider removing.